# The method 'truncate' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: truncate()

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, ratingbar

I'm getting this error while showing rating from firebase to ratingbarindicator. Please help
Here is my ratingbarindicator code:

```
RatingBarIndicator(
                  rating: widget.doctor.rating,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Icon(
                        Icons.star,
                        color: Colors.amber,
                      ),
                  itemCount: 5,
                  itemSize: 15.0,
                  direction: Axis.horizontal),
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the code inside the class `RatingBarIndicator`, the [`truncate()`](https://github.com/sarbagyastha/flutter_rating_bar/blob/master/lib/src/rating_bar_indicator.dart#L62) method is being called on the `rating` property:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _ratingNumber = widget.rating.truncate() + 1;
    _ratingFraction = widget.rating - _ratingNumber + 1;
  }
```

Therefore the value of `widget.doctor.rating` is null and that's why you get this error.